# How can I get the value I updated on one page on another page with mobx?

Tags: flutter, mobx

I want to check the index value with Mobx. Dropdown also

```
viewmodel.setValue(value: viewmodel.values.indexOf(value));
```

When I send it this way, my index value is updated on the mobx side. But when I wrap the widget with Observer in the Product section and call the index and indexxx values, they always come back as zero.How can I track it with Mobx and get the value I changed in dropdown on the Product page?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_architecture/core/base/model/base_view_model.dart';
import 'package:mobx/mobx.dart';
part 'home_view_model.g.dart';

class HomeViewModel = _HomeViewModelBase with _$HomeViewModel;

abstract class _HomeViewModelBase with Store, BaseViewModel {
  // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables

  @override
  void setContext(BuildContext? context) => context = context;

  void init() {
    dropdownValue = values.first;
    indexxx;
    setValue(value: 0);
  }

  @observable
  int? index;
  @computed
  int? get indexxx => this.index;
  @observable
  bool isLoading = false;
  @observable
  List<String> values = [
    'Cart',
    'Product',
    'Order',
  ];
  @action
  int? setValue({int? value}) {
    if (value != null) {
      index = value;
    }
    debugPrint("mboxxvalueee:`$index`");
    debugPrint("newmobxvaluesss:`$indexxx`");
    return index;
  }

  @observable
  String? dropdownValue;
}




 /*  @action
  int? setValue({int? value}) {
    if (value != null) {
      index = value;
    }
    // debugPrint("mboxxvalueee:`$index`");
    return index;
  } */
```

I want to check it with Mobx and get the value I changed in Dropdown with the updated value on the Product page.